# How can I enable USB Debugging and WiFi on a locked phone?

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi, android-4.4-kitkat

I am on a Android 4.4 'HTC One SV' Phone. I don't know the password and it has asked me for google user and pass, but the wifi is turned off and im not sure if I know the password. USB Debugging is also off and I cant access settings since it is locked.

How can I turn wifi on through ADB with USB Debugging off and no way of accessing phone. ADB is not recognising the phone which I believe is because USB Debugging is off. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

USB Debugging simply can't be enabled via root. Normally OEMs put a bypass such as swiping from the swype symbol to the letter S to open Google Now via Swype Keyboard. Also, this typically means the phone was stolen and the thief used the Recovery menu to format the device.